# Opencv detect intruse in irregular polygon area

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a DIY video surveillance system in my home with raspberry via rtsp stream from an ip cam. I'm not very experienced with opencv and python but these days I'm still trying to learn how to use them. I am sure that my problem could be simple for many.

I'm using a tracking code downloaded from github and customized it to my needs. I can easily detect the presence of a subject in a square area established by me simply with these commands:

```
_, contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours0:
    area_detect = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area_detect > minsize_detect and area_detect < maxsize_detect:

        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        cy = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cx = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        # Detect in area point
        if cx in range(Area_up_pnt,Area_down_pnt) and cy in range(Area_left_pnt,Area_right_pnt):
            count_in_area += 1;
```

I can also identify the intrusion side from the left-right lines of the square with these commands:

```
for i in persons:
    if abs(cx-i.getX()) <= h and abs(cy-i.getY()) <= w:
        # update coordinates
        i.updateCoords(cx,cy)

        # Verso sx
        if i.goline_SX(LINE_rightarea_pnt,LINE_rightarea_pnt) and cx in range(Area_up_pnt,Area_down_pnt):
             countleftinside += 1;
```

The code works fine, but based only on the x, y coordinates in a regular square I don't get the precision I want. The area in fact should be an irregular polygon, like this:[image]

I hope the image will help you understand what I want to achieve. I thank you in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume u just want it to be not normal rect like shape

Try with opencv **minrect**.

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
```

[image]

And if you need it to be irregular shape, try with opencv convexhull

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I was unclear. Suppose that is detected a person from live rtsp stream in motion and that provides the coordinating cx, cy of his centroid with the code written above. If the area of interest was a regular square my code simply determines whether the centroid x, y is within the range of the sides of the square. But if the area of my interest is an irregular polygon how do I determine if the intruder is inside or not? and which of its lines is exceeded on entry and exit?

Comment: Assuming you have the convelhull A setup.  simply run the convexhull function with corners of converxhull A and your input centroid x and y. After this step you will have convexhull B. If the resulting convelhull B is same as A before, then there is a intruder inside. If it sounds too complicated. Just follow this link to determine whether a point is inside or not.  https://salzis.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/convex-hull-how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-inside-or-outside/

Comment: Ok this solves in full the problem of detection in the area. To detect which of the lines of the polygon the intruder has passed?

Comment: find the distance between the intruder centroid and   middle point between convexhull corners.    sort this distance array.    Then the shortest one gives you the "which of the lines of the polygon the intruder has passed"

Comment: PS. i got my own home detector. I dont bother all of those. If people who enter did not switch off the trap, then he will be facing the power of THOR. haha. As in where did I place those trap, I cant really disclose.